# Enumerate top-level tags inside another tag

Tags: javascript, html, xml-parsing

Bet it is kinda basics, but I don’t know how to do that.

I have an xml, it has `ModelList` tag, that includes a lot of `Model` tags, which, also includes  **also** `Model` tags:

```
<ModelList>
    <Model name="Name">
         <Model name="SubName" id="ID"></Model>
         ...
    </Model>
    <Model name="Name2">
         <Model name="SubName2" id="ID2"></Model>
         ...
    </Model>
</ModelList>
```

Top-level `Model` tags stand for vehicle marks, low-level for models.

I have 2 js strings: car Mark and car Model, I need to find model’s id.

Unfortunately, I have never been working with xml a lot, honestly, so I asking for help.

The only stuff I did is

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

var element = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ModelList")[0];
```

So, I think, next I need to go through all top-level `Model` and compare their `Name` attribute with my mark’s string. If they are equal, then do the same for inner `Model` tags, searching for model.

I thought it should be something like

```
for(var i=0;i<element.length;i++)
   if(element[i].Name==MarkString)
     for(var j=0;j<element[i].length;j++)
   if(element[i][j].Name==ModelString)
        return element[i][j].id;
```

But unfortunately, `element` doesn’t have `length` property.

Comment: Can you edit your question and, first show what `MarkString` and `ModelString` and, second, given your sample xml, what exactly is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

To get top-level childs array of some node you should use `childNodes` property:

```
domElement.childNodes
```

That is an object, that supports `length` property.

Also, for my case there is no need in `getElementsByTagName` method. So for my case, the solution is:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

for(var i=0; i<xmlDoc.childNodes.length; i++)
  if(xmlDoc.childNodes[i].getAttribute('Name') == MarkString)
for(var j=0; j<xmlDoc.childNodes[i].childNodes.length; j++)
  if(xmlDoc.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].getAttribute('Name') == ModelString)
    return element[i][j].id;
```